# Spark2.2 interpreter on Zeppelin 0.7.0 running on HDP 2.6

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

Simply trying to test a Zeppelin interpreter to run Spark 2.2 on YARN on Zeppelin 0.7.0(HDP2.6) but repeatedly getting:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig
```

All I am running is

```
%spark2 
sc.version
```

With the same Spark 2.2 I can run spark-submit s and spark-shell operations running on YARN(locally and remotely) but can't make Zeppelin listen to this new version of Spark. Does Zeppelin-HDP only support Spark 2.1 and 1.6? (My Spark 2.2 is a custom installation).

The only thing that makes me believe the above is that i can see in the logs of testing the Zeppelin notebook:
 `Added JAR file:/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0.2.6.0.3-8.jar`

which appears to be a HDP-specific zeppelin JAR.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. I was hitting a similar issue while I was running zeppelin `0.7.0` and spark `2.2.0` on mesos. Infact have a look at this commit:

https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/commit/28310c2b95785d8b9e63bc0adc5a26df8b3c9dec

The support seems to be added in `0.7.3` so try upgrading zeppelin and give it a try. I built zeppelin from `master` branch  and it worked for me but the tag `v0.7.3` should work fine as well.